# Null pointer exception while using Trigger.newMap.keySet()

Tags: apex, trigger, controller, custom-controller

I have a requirement to update contact field on MC Subscriber Activity when the contact email id matches with MC Subscriber Activities field.

Below is my trigger:

```
trigger MCActivityonContact on MC4SF__MC_Subscriber_Activity__c (before insert, before update) {

    Map<string,Contact> mapAccountCodeWithAccount = new Map<string,Contact>();

    for (Contact Con : [select id,email from Contact where Email != Null ]){
        
        mapAccountCodeWithAccount.put(Con.Email,Con);
    }
   list<string> lstSplittedFields = new list<string>();
    set<Id> ids = trigger.newMap.keySet();
    List<MC4SF__MC_Subscriber_Activity__c> activitiesWithSubscriber = [SELECT Contact__c, MC4SF__MC_Subscriber__r.Name FROM MC4SF__MC_Subscriber_Activity__c WHERE Id IN :ids];
    lstSplittedFields =  activitiesWithSubscriber[0].MC4SF__MC_Subscriber__r.Name.split('-');
    for(MC4SF__MC_Subscriber_Activity__c mc : trigger.new){
        
        if(mc.MC4SF__MC_Subscriber__c != null){
        if(mc.Contact__c ==null){
            if(mapAccountCodeWithAccount.containsKey(lstSplittedFields[0].trim())){
                mc.Contact__c = mapAccountCodeWithAccount.get(lstSplittedFields[0].trim()).Id;
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

But when the above trigger condition is met, I am getting null pointer exception for trigger.newmap.keySet() for before insert. However, for before update, it is working fine as expected.

Can anyone please suggest the changes from the above code so that i can get this work for before insert as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the parent records directly in a map, something like:

```
Map<Id, MC4SF__MC_Subscriber__c> parents = new Map<Id, sObject>();
for(MC4SF__MC_Subscriber_Activity__c mc : trigger.new) {
  parents.put(mc.MC4SF__MC_Subscriber__c, null);
}
parents.putAll([SELECT Name FROM MC4SF__MC_Subscriber__c WHERE Id = :parents.keySet()]);
Map<String, Id> contactByEmail = new Map<String, Id>();
for(MC4SF__MC_Subscriber_Activity__c mc: trigger.new) {
  MC4SF__MC_Subscriber__c subscriber = parents.get(mc.MC4SF__MC_Subscriber__c);
  if(subscriber != null) {
    contactByEmail.put(subscriber.Name.split('-')[0].trim(), null);
  }
}
for(Contact record: [select email from contact where email = :contactByEmail.keySet()]) {
  contactByEmail.put(record.Email, record.Id);
}
for(MC4SF__MC_Subscriber_Activity__c mc: Trigger.new) {
  MC4SF__MC_Subscriber__c subscriber = parents.get(mc.MC4SF__MC_Subscriber__c);
  if(subscriber != null) {
    mc.Contact__c = contactByEmail.get(subscriber.Name.split('-')[0].trim());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, as always, your suggestion worked!